# opencv waitkey, imprecise, not working o so?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm developing a video player with C++ and OpenCV, and need high precision, but when I make a cv::waitKey, the function never waits the specified miliseconds:

```
    tWait.resetAndRestart();
    cv::waitKey((int)(30));
    realDelay = tWait.getElapsedMsec();
    cout << "realDelay :: " << realDelay.count() << "\n";
```

This is the awesone output

```
...
realDelay :: 25
realDelay :: 24
realDelay :: 25
realDelay :: 21
realDelay :: 21
realDelay :: 24
realDelay :: 24
realDelay :: 20
realDelay :: 25
....
```

Any idea?

Edit:
This is the timer initialization, but I think that the problem it's not here.

```
void timer::start() {
    //Start the timer
    started = true;

    //Unpause the timer
    paused = false;

    //Get the current clock time    
    //startMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime);
    startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  
}

void timer::reset()
{
    paused = false;
    started = false;
    startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    pauseMs = std::chrono::milliseconds(0);
}

inline std::chrono::milliseconds timer::getElapsedMsec( void )
{
//  return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now());
    //If the timer is running
    if( started == true )
    {
        //If the timer is paused
        if( paused == true )
        {
            //Return the number of ticks when the timer was paused
            return pauseMs;
        }
        else
        {
            //Return the current time minus the start time
            return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime);
        }    
    }

    //If the timer isn't running
    return std::chrono::milliseconds(0);   
}
```

Comment: It's also possible that your timing solution is the one that is imprecise. You don't post it's initialization so it's impossible to tell.

Comment: The [Docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) clearly says that `since the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the function will not wait exactly delay ms, it will wait at least delay ms, depending on what else is running on your computer at that time`

Comment: Haris, the wait time sometimes is bigger and othertimes less, as you can see in the output... with a 30ms delay, always 20-25 real delay

Comment: If you under Windows, then try multimedia timer ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742877(v=vs.85).aspx ). I don't know if it exists in linux.

Comment: @Haris the performance of waitKey is actually terrible for me. I can close all applications except for my python IDE, run the video player with waitKey(1) and end up waiting for 25-35 ms. This is unacceptable behavior. Is there a solution to it? Running on OSX with most recent opencv.

Comment: @PaulSeeb  Yo mean waitKey(1) alone takes 25-35 ms or all of your code inside while() loop?.

Comment: @Haris waitKey(1) alone. I measure time before and after the waitKey call and it takes 25-30 ms. Mind this is in python.

Comment: In my opinion waitkey() is not meant for such an accurate time delay, you could use usleep() or sleep().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a good solution:
First, I compute the desired delay, then use the minimum value in cvWaitKey and measure the real delay, and then use std::this_thread::sleep_for (who is really exact)with the corrected value:

```
    delayMeasure0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    cv::waitKey((int)(1));          
    delayMeasure1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    delta = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(delayMeasure1-delayMeasure0);
    computedDelay -= delta;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(computedDelay);
```